# NullPointerException for Seemingly no reason

Tags: java, greenfoot

I've been trying to learn Java using Greenfoot, yet this code always seems to throw a `NullPointerException` no matter what I try. I've tried using a pointer, not using a pointer, and even changing the scope, and nothing works.
The code looks like this.

```
import java.util.*;
import greenfoot.*;

/**
 * 
 */

public class TurtleActor extends Actor
{
    public MouseInfo mouse = Greenfoot.getMouseInfo();

    /**
     * Act - do whatever the turtle wants to do. This method is called whenever the 'Act' or 'Run' button gets pressed in the environment.
     */
    public void act()
    {
        setLocation(mouse.getX(), 100);
    }
}
```

Please help, I cannot tell what is wrong. Either I made a really stupid mistake, or it doesn't work.

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You only initialize `mouse` at start-up, but not later.

Additionally, `getMouseInfo()` will return `null`, if the mouse is outside the world boundary.

The moment you start the scenario, the mouse is not inside the world. Consequently, `mouse` is `null`.

The solution is to call `getMouseInfo()` in `act()`, **and** to check that its result is not `null` before accessing a member method.

Please read the documentation.